# How to find the area underneath a set of points and multiply by a variable before integration?

Tags: python, math, calculus

Basically I am trying to integrate something of the following form:

[image]

The "data" in the image would be the area under the curve of a set of data points. Without the additional "t" in the integrand, I am able to integrate it just fine without any issues. However, I cannot find a way to symbolically multiply each of the data points by "t" and then integrate over t. I have tried the trapz function from NumPy and the simps function from scipy. Both result in an array of every data entry value multiplied by t which I clearly do not want. If it helps, I do have bounds of the integral, so it should yield a definite answer.

Hopefully my question is clear, and it isn't too obvious. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edited: to fit guidelines.

Comment: Maybe `sympy`, but questions that ask about library recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Are you expecting a symbolic answer (as a function of `t`) or are you expecting a numeric answer? If it's the latter, since you probably already know the `t` at each `data`, can't you simply multiply them element-wise and `trapz` the result? (slightly rusty on math, maybe this is not correct)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I can do that, but I actually was not sure if I could do that either. I am also rusty on my math.

Comment: I do not know why the question was closed. Unfortunately it looks like you cannot do a simple multiplication of the data points by t. Consider this example: https://i.imgur.com/sWXFl6Y.png Here you can see four data points in blue ((0,8), (4,2), (6,12), (10,6)); then  those four data points multiplied by t in yellow; then every point of the blue curve multiplied by t in green. The integral you seek is the area under the green curve, which is more complicated than the yellow curve.

Comment: @Stef that depends on the numerical integration method you use. `trapz` uses the [trapezoidal rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrapezoidalRule.html), which would approximate the area of the green curve to that of the orange one. If you had a smaller `delta_t`, then you'd have a higher resolution for the orange curve and it'd be closer to the green curve.

Comment: There is no "delta_t" appearing in the construction of the yellow curve. The yellow curve is constructed from the values at the data points. Approximating the area under the green curve by the area under the yellow curve looks like there would be a huge approximation error.

Comment: I am voting to reopen since the question has been adequately edited.